# Ionic Alert dialogue with Select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Creating an ionic alert box allows you the possibility to add multiple input elements like text, paragraph, URL, radio, checkbox, etc. For example, the checkbox inside the alert looks like this:

[image]

I want a functionality to be able to add a `select` element with multiple dropdown options.

Comment: I would  suggest you to use modal for this scenario. Its more flexible and you can customize UI as per your Requirements. you can set with height on modal to look like this alert.

Comment: And Ugly hack would be like pass your Html to `message` Option in your alert.  it will show it like select options. but i don't know how it will behave.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by another user, you can try to use [ion-modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) for this as you can customize it to look exactly how you want.

However for the simple alert you need, you can use [ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select). It even has your exact example on the page (see "Operating Systems" example on Android, top right).

```
   <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Operating System</ion-label>
      <ion-select mode="md" ok-text="Okay" cancel-text="Nah">
        <ion-select-option value="dos">DOS</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="lunix">Linux</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="mac7">Mac OS 7</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="mac8">Mac OS 8</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="win3.1">Windows 3.1</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="win95">Windows 95</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="win98">Windows 98</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```